# No se carga el enlace de una web creada con VUE

Tags: vue.js, .htaccess

tengo una web con NUXT que coge noticias de una API de WP en JSON.

Si voy al enlace del Blog de la misma web https://www.arquerosderubi.com/posts/ y pulso sobre la noticia que quiero, se carga correctamente.

Pero si cojo el enlace, lo copio y lo pego en otra pestaña del navegador, no funciona.

https://www.arquerosderubi.com/post/segunda-tirada-de-la-liga-iniciat-2021/

Se que es un problema de configuración de servidor pero no encuentro como solucionarlo.

Intenté poner en el .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /www/post/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Pero me da error 500

¿Alguna idea de como arreglarlo?

Gracias

Comment: No veo la manera de depurar una redirección si no indicas claramente qué quieres que se invoque internamente cuándo llega una petición a la ruta que ya has indicado.

Comment: VUE hace pasar todo por el index.html y desde allí, coge las variables pasadas, en este caso POST para cargar la pagina POST y el titulo del articulo para hacer la busqueda